# pandas correlation lower than -1

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I had wanted to filter 1 and -1 correlations from my dataframe but I have realised that some of the correlations slightly bigger than 1 and lower than -1.

I couldn't find what is the real reason behind that.  I have put subset of the dataframe here.

```
ModelID      RPL23A         ST13
ACH-001196  -4.384573196    0.025759764
ACH-000054  -4.384573196    0.025759764
ACH-001050  -4.384573196    0.025759764
ACH-000505  -4.81558301     0.44097594
ACH-001794  -4.384573196    0.025759764
```

example code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0)
corr = df.corr()
```

and if I want to filter 1 correlations, I can not

```
corr[corr == -1.0]
```

[image]

and I checked what is the reason behind that, it seems they are not -1

```
corr.stack().reset_index().astype(str)
```

[image]

Comment: Floating point math is imprecise: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details.

Comment: @not_speshal I don't understand why you closed the topic, I know that floating point math is imprecise but I wanted to emphasize that correlation function should round this, you calculate correlation with pandas and then you can not filter this?

Comment: It's still just a numerical precision issue. See [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35135).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only looking at correlations equal to EXACTLY -1 you could filter out any that are less than or equal to -1. For example:

```
corr[column for column in corr.columns if any(corr[column] <= -1)]
```

This would catch the cases where your correlation is -1.00007 (probably due to overflow). You can also do this technique within a range of a threshold

Comment: @tyasird in case you're still looking for help